# Missing Right Parenthesis error while executing this query in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am executing this query in oracle and it is giving me an error of missing right parenthesis at line 33. Is there anyone who can help me resolve this issue. Thank you
Here is my query

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.EMPNO,
         RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FIRSTNAME,
         RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.LASTNAME,
         RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE,
         RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat,
         RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC
  FROM   RM_LIVE.EMPBASE,
         RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE,
         RM_LIVE.CRWBASE,
         RM_LIVE.EMPNAME,
         RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC,
         RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC,
         RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT,
         RM_LIVE.CRWCAT
  where  RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.IDEMPNO = RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.IDCRWBASE = RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.IDCRWBASE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO = RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.IDEMPNO 
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC =RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC  
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.IDEMPNO =RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.IDEMPNO=RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.IDEMPNO 
  AND    RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.IDCRWCAT = RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.IDCRWCAT
  AND    RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat IN ('CP','FO','CM','MC')
  AND    RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE <> 'XYZ'
  AND    RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC IN  
                ('921','2' ,'1','301','17','4','3','7','302' ,'861','31',
                 '723','30','722 ','29 ','721','16','601','581')  
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPBASE.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPSPECFUNC.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FROMDATE <=SYSDATE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.STARTDATE <= SYSDATE
  AND    RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE AS ta  (EMPNO,EMPFIRSTNAME,EMPLASTNAME, Base, CAT, code)
) 
SELECT  DISTINCT
        t.EMPNO,
        t.EMPFIRSTNAME,
        t.EMPLASTNAME,
        t.Base,
        t.CAT, 
        (ABS(oa.val1) * NVL(NULLIF((ABS(oa.val2) * ABS(oa.val3)),0),1) * ABS(oa.val4)  * ABS(oa.val5) * ABS(oa.val6) * ABS(oa.val7) * ABS(oa.val8) * ABS(oa.val9)) AS "FTE VALUE"
 FROM   t
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (1,2,4) THEN 0.70 ELSE -1 END) AS val1,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (1,2) THEN 0  ELSE -1 END) AS val2,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (4) THEN 1.29  ELSE -1 END) AS val3,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN ( 861 ) THEN 0.80  ELSE -1 END) AS val4
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (921,301,30,722,601,581) THEN 0.50   ELSE -1 END) AS val5
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (17,302,16) THEN 0.85 ELSE -1 END) AS val6
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (29,721) THEN 0.25 ELSE -1 END) AS val7
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (31,723) THEN 0.75 ELSE -1 END) AS val8
                        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code IN (3,7) THEN 0.90 ELSE -1 END) AS val9
                  FROM t AS t2 WHERE t2.EMPNO = t.EMPNO) oa
```

Comment: Please don't mix legacy (comma) joins and ANSI/ISO joins - just convert everything to ANSI joins (it is so much easier to see how the tables are related).

Comment: What does `OUTER APPLY` do? Is that syntax from another DBMS? And what is the `AS ta (EMPNO,EMPFIRSTNAME,EMPLASTNAME, Base, CAT, code)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @AlexPoole `OUTER APPLY` appears to be a [12c feature](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABJHDDA) - however, the OP has only tagged earlier versions of Oracle.

Comment: @MTO - yes, just found that in [new features](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT165), thanks. I really must start to get to grips with 12c...

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your sub-query factoring (`WITH ... AS ( ... )`) clause is:

```
AND    RM_LIVE.EMPQUALCAT.ENDDATE >= SYSDATE AS ta  (EMPNO,EMPFIRSTNAME,EMPLASTNAME, Base, CAT, code)
```

The `AS ta (...)` is invalid syntax.

If you want to name the columns then you need to delete that part and change the first line to:

```
WITH t (EMPNO,EMPFIRSTNAME,EMPLASTNAME, Base, CAT, code) AS (
```

However, that is syntax introduced in Oracle 11g and won't work in Oracle 10g - if you want to support that version (and it seems you do since you've tagged it) then just explicitly alias each column:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT RM_LIVE.EMPLOYEE.EMPNO,
         RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.FIRSTNAME AS EMPFIRSTNAME,
         RM_LIVE.EMPNAME.LASTNAME AS EMPLASTNAME,
         RM_LIVE.CRWBASE.BASE,
         RM_LIVE.CRWCAT.crwcat AS CAT,
         RM_LIVE.CRWSPECFUNC.IDCRWSPECFUNC AS CODE
```